# How can I find all recursive combinations of different size Strings in an ArrayList? - See example

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

Clearly, that is almost impossible to understand.

So, here is an example:
If I have an ArrayList = ["abc", "def"]
Then the result I desire is:

```
ad ae af 
bd be bf 
cd ce cf
```

And the same can be assumed if I have an ArrayList = ["ab", "cd", "efg"]:

```
ace acf acg
ade adf adg
bce bcf bcg
bde bdf bdg
```

Where all the options are shown. The first index String corresponds to the first 'potential' letter of the result. The second corresponds with the second, and so forth. I have been looking into different forms of recursion, but I seem to have run into a hole. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();
    param.add("jkl");
    param.add("mno");
    param.add("pqrs");
    System.out.println(giveFrag(param, 0));
}
static String giveLetter(String s, int indexForString) {
    // return the letter given
    return s.substring(indexForString, indexForString+1);
}
static String giveFrag(ArrayList<String> strs, int start) {
    String output = "";
    if (start == strs.size()-1) {
        output = giveLetter(strs.get(start),0);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.get(start).length(); i++) {
            String q = strs.get(start).substring(i,i+1);
            output += q;
            for (int k = strs.size()-1; k < strs.size(); k++) {
                output += giveFrag(strs, start+1);
            }
            output += " ";
        }
        output += "\n";
    }
    return output;
}
```

NOTICE THAT FOR SIMPLICITY'S SAKE, I IGNORE THE LAST ELEMENT OF THE ARRAYLIST. THIS CAN BE SEEN IN THE IF STATEMENT OF giveFrag().

Currently, my result is as follows:

```
jmp np op 
 kmp np op 
 lmp np op
```

Now, to the actual question! First of all, if anyone spots any glaring errors that would produce this result instead of:

```
jmp jnp jop
kmp knp kop
lmp lnp lop
```

Please let me know. If there aren't any obvious ones, and an entire restructure is needed, could you please be very specific for what I should be doing instead?

In addition, if anyone has any additional time on their hands, could they find a way to include the last array element when iterating?

Thanks so much for your help, and sorry for the incredibly vague title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current output doesn't match the description of the problem.
The first line of the output should be:

```
jmp jmq jmr jms
```

The implementation is not really close to what you need.
Consider this instead:

```
private void accumulateFrags(List<String> strings, int start, String prefix, List<String> frags) {
  if (start == strings.size()) {
    frags.add(prefix);
    return;
  }
  String current = strings.get(start);
  for (char c : current.toCharArray()) {
    accumulateFrags(strings, start + 1, prefix + c, frags);
  }
}
```

This function will accumulate all combinations in a list.
Call it like this:

```
List<String> frags = new ArrayList<>();
accumulateFrags(Arrays.asList("jkl", "mno", "pqrs"), 0, "", frags);
System.out.println(frags);
```

This doesn't produce the line by line output you desire.
But that should be fairly straightforward to do,
so I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong now! It seems to me that I was not iterating over each of the characters in each of the fragments. Oh, and to answer why the result was incorrect, that was because I overly simplified it. See the NOTICE under the code. Thanks so much for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

recursive

```
// arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String arr[] = {"jkl", "mno", "pqrs"};

List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
constructStr(res, "", 0, arr);


String s = "";
for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++) {
  int mod = arr[arr.length-1].length();
  if (i % mod == 0) {
    System.out.println(s); 
    s = res.get(i) + " ";
  }
  else {
    s += res.get(i) + " ";
  }
}
System.out.println(s); 
}

private static void constructStr(List<String> result, String curStr, int i, String arr[]) {
if (i + 1 < arr.length) {
  for (int k=0; k<arr[i].length(); k++) {
    constructStr(result, curStr + arr[i].charAt(k), i + 1, arr);
  }
}
else {
  for (int k=0; k<arr[i].length(); k++) {
    result.add(curStr + arr[i].charAt(k));
  }
}    
}
```